# Difficulty developing unique dynamic onclick events in Javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am working with a decent sized set of data relating to objects on the page and some objects need links applied to them onclick. The link to connect to is part of the dataset and I build a string for the link with the variable **linkTarget** and apply it like so.

```
 if (dataTag[i][3]==true){

    if(prepend==undefined || prepend=="undefined"){                         
        var linkTarget=ResultsJSON["targetUrl"];
        ele.onclick = function(){
            window.open(linkTarget);
        };
    } else {
        var linkTarget=prepend+ResultsJSON["targetUrl"];
        ele.onclick = function(){
            window.open(linkTarget);
        };
    }
```

ele refers to an element picked up with getElementByID. Now I am going through quite a few objects and the problem I have is the onclick for every object is the last value of linkTarget. This is all contained in a function and link target is a local variable so I have no idea why. I have tried using an array with something like

```
ele.onclick=function(){window.open(linkTarget[linkTarget.length-1]);};
```

and even

```
ele.onclick=function(){window.open(linkTarget.valueOf());};
```

with the same results. I am at a loss now and would appreciate any help.

Comment: My spider sense tells me you fell in the classic closures in for-loops trap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in a loop — therefore, you need to put your things-to-be-executed in another function, like so:

```
 if(dataTag[i][3]) {
    if(prepend) {   
        (function(linkTarget) {
            ele.onclick = function() {
                window.open(linkTarget);
            };
        })(ResultsJSON.targetUrl);
    } else {
        (function(linkTarget) {
            ele.onclick = function() {
                window.open(linkTarget);
            };
        })(ResultsJSON.targetUrl);
    }
```

I also made some general corrections.

Comment: Thank You I was banging my head on this problem

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate your data and watch your troubles melt away.

```
dataTag.forEach(function (item) {
    if (item[3]==true) {
        var linkTarget = "";
        if (prepend==undefined || prepend=="undefined") {
            linkTarget = prepend;
        }
        linkTarget += ResultsJSON.targetUrl;
        ele.onclick = function () {
            window.open(linkTarget);
        };
    }
});
```

See this [compatibility note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Compatibility) for using `Array.forEach()` in older browsers.

Comment: did you mean "... and watch `this` problems start to pop up"? :P

Comment: Ya, maybe.  The solution requires calling a function one way or another.  Dealing with the new context is unavoidable.  At least with `.forEach()` you are able to specify the value of `this` via the second argument.